# sql server execution plan - which query performance well

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am learning SQL Server 2008 execution plan and for testing I have run two queries and tried to compare the results.

Is first query running faster than the second one? I normally check the execution cost (performance and cost).

**First Query**

[image]

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(931 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Visits'. Scan count 2, logical reads 1235, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Assignments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4657, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 203 ms,  elapsed time = 198 ms.
```

**Second Query**

[image]

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Visits'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19335, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Assignments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4657, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 109 ms,  elapsed time = 250 ms.
```

Comment: You need to look at (and provide here, if you want us to compare) the execution cost and the values for `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` - everything together should give you an idea of which query works better in terms of performance

Comment: i don't know why second imgae is not very clear.

Comment: I have added the execution time stats

Comment: Why don't you just execute both at the same time, and the excecution plan will display the relative cost of both queries in the batch. While it's not 100% reliable since your test query itself does not represent every variation of such queries handled in production, it's still close enough in this case here. Say the above query uses up 15% of the batch resources while the one below uses 85%. Then you add more data to the table, and the above query drops down to 10% while the one below rises to 90%. At that point it's pretty obvious which one is more effective. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is faster, according to the statistics output. Things to look for in there include the elapsed time, and number of reads/writes.

1st query:

`SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 203 ms, elapsed time = 198 ms.`

2nd query:

`SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 109 ms, elapsed time = 250 ms.`

The first query performs slightly faster. Milliseconds might seem trivial, but consider that for a query that is run literally thousands of times a day, and all these tiny bits of seconds will start adding up quickly.

Another thing to look for is the reads and writes (which will represent the amount of work that has to be done to get the resultset retrieved.

1st query:

`(931 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Visits'. Scan count 2, **logical reads 1235**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Assignments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4657, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.`

2nd query:

`(1 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Visits'. Scan count 1, **logical reads 19335**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Assignments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4657, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.`

`Logical reads` in this case represent data retrieved from the buffer cache, which is less expensive than `physical reads`, where the data is retrieved from the physical disk (and that's expensive). Still, less is better.

In this case, your first query runs in less time (elapsed time = `198ms` vs `250ms`), and requires less reads than the second query, (`1235` vs `19335`), and therefore is preferred over the second one.

One additional tip, in the execution plan, thicker bars represent more data being passed. However, while they can give you a visual clue, be sure to validate the results of it, as I've experienced situations where the displayed execution plan was not accurate.